# Run Keyword If with SQL

Tags: frameworks, robotframework

I am attempting to pull back data from a Restful web service.

If I get a text value that contains word A,  then I need to run this SQL to verify, if it doesn't, run a different SQL.

This run Keyword If wants to run a keyword,  but the Query statement starts with a variable.

This is what I've tried:

```
${typeA}    Set Variable    ${rowValues["TypeA"]}
${foundValue}    Get Lines Containing String  ${typeA}  Speical
${lineCount}    Get Line Count    ${foundValue}
${resultValue}  Set Variable If   ${lineCount} > 0   ${True}   ${False}
${idvalue}  Set Variable    test
Run Keyword If    ${resultValue}
...    ${idvalue}  Query  Select max(id) from test where 1 =1;    
...    ELSE
...    ${idValue}  Query  Select max(id) from table 2 where 1 = 1;
```

I just get this error:

```
FAIL : No keyword with name 'test' found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument after the condition in `Run keyword if` must be a keyword. You are incorrectly giving it a variable (which presumably contains the string "test", based on the error you're reporting)

To assign the value of the query you must capture the result of `Run keyword if`:

```
${idValue}=  Run keyword if  ${resultValue}
...  Query  Select max(id) from test where 1 =1;
...  ELSE
...  Query  Select max(id) from table 2 where i = 1;
```